# How do i clear rows in Excel using EPPLus library?

Tags: c#, epplus

Right now I am providing hard code value as I know the number of rows
in excel that has data in it.I would like my program knows how to clear the excel and import new data every time in excel sheet. How do I achieve this using EPPlus v4.1.1?

My Code:*

```
 using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(sourcefile + fileName)))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[myWS];

                    int hardCodedRowNumber = 300;

                    ws.DeleteRow(2, hardCodedRowNumber);
// Other codes to import data from db after clearing excel 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest and most reliable way is to delete the entire worksheet.

```
var oldSheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[myWS];
xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(oldSheet);
var newSheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MyNewSheet");
```

and from there set up line 1 from scratch.

If you strive to keep line 1 as is, you can create the new worksheet first, and copy the lines from one to the other before deleting the old worksheet:

```
oldSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, oldSheet.Dimension.End.Column].Copy(newSheet.Cells[1, 1]);
```

Alternatively, using your own method, you can replace your "hardCodedRowNumber" with

```
ws.Dimension.End.Row
```

Comment: There are some columns which have functions those look ups other sheets in excel. So i do want to keep those columns and formula. For the time being what i did is i manually deleted all the data and saved the Excel file as an template and every time I need to create report, I copy the file and saved in different location and import the data on it. Sir could please show me how do I create own method using ws.Dimension.End.Row . Thank you Sir

Comment: Try to replace ws.DeleteRow(2, hardCodedRowNumber); with ws.DeleteRow(2, ws.Dimension.End.Row);

Comment: ws.DeleteRow(2, ws.Dimension.End.Row); This worked sir. But I ran into another issues. Some columns in the row has formula/functions in it. While deleting rows it clears out the functions as well. Is there a way to let program now which specific columns to clear instead of clearing rows ?

Comment: Then you must either iterate through every cell and check. If your sheet has a static layout where formulas and values are placed, you may clear out single cells with hard coded references using ws.Cells["B3"].Clear() or larger areas with ws.Cells["B6:D19"].Clear() and so on.